# How to run AWS instances with attached ephemeral disks with the fog library

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fog

I would like to know if there is an equivalent option of "--block-device-mapping" in `ec2-run-instances` command line to attach ephemeral disks on AWS instances with the fog library.

There is a reference on `BlockDeviceMappings` in the fog source code. But since the documentation is a bit terse and I'm not a ruby expert, any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the command line equates to `<devicename>=<blockdevice>`. So we should be able to do that in fog in one of a couple ways. The model version using your values would be something like:

```
compute = Fog::Compute.new(...)

compute.servers.create(
  :block_device_mapping => [
    { 'deviceName' => '/dev/sdb', 'virtualName' => 'ephemeral0' },
    { 'deviceName' => '/dev/sdc', 'virtualName' => 'ephemeral1' },
    { 'deviceName' => '/dev/sdd', 'virtualName' => 'ephemeral2' },
    { 'deviceName' => '/dev/sde', 'virtualName' => 'ephemeral3' },
  ],
  :image_id => 'ami-xxxxxxxx'
)
```

Or the lower level, more direct path might look like:

```
compute.run_instances(
  'ami-xxxxxxxx',
  1,
  1,
  :block_device_mapping => [
    { 'deviceName' => '/dev/sdb', 'virtualName' => 'ephemeral0' },
    { 'deviceName' => '/dev/sdc', 'virtualName' => 'ephemeral1' },
    { 'deviceName' => '/dev/sdd', 'virtualName' => 'ephemeral2' },
    { 'deviceName' => '/dev/sde', 'virtualName' => 'ephemeral3' },
  ]
)
```

I would recommend the higher-level one as it is a bit easier to use/understand (and sets some nice defaults for you). Hopefully that gets closer to a good solution for you, but happy to continue discussing.

Comment: An equivalent could be `ec2-run-instances ami-xxxxxxxx -b '/dev/sdb=ephemeral0' -b '/dev/sdc=ephemeral1' -b '/dev/sdd=ephemeral2' -b '/dev/sde=ephemeral3'. Also, when you're trying to launch an instance thru the AWS console wizard, there's options to attach disk to the instance to launch. I can't figure if we can run instances with these options via fog

Comment: Also, the main idea, if it's possible, to add the support of this in the vagrant-aws plugin